# Is 空きました read as both すきました and あきました?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation

I just learned one way to say ''I'm hungry'' in Japanese.

お腹が空きました

Can this be read as both すきました and あきました ?

If not then what is the difference here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60942/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32870/9831

Comment: To be quite clear: in the context you gave, すきました is the only appropriate reading. In other contexts, it could vary.